# Undeclared Identifier FIRAuth

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner in iOS and fire base.

- I installed firebase cocoa pods.
- Imported `firebase.h` in my `loginViewcontroller.h`
- Added pod 'Firebase/Core', 
  pod 'Firebase/Database', 
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'.

I am migrating from parse to firebase, I added following fire base authentication code in my `loginViewController.m`.

`[[FIRAuth auth]
         createUserWithEmail:email
         password:password
         completion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user,
                      NSError *_Nullable error) {
             // ...
         }];`

But it shows an error called `use of undeclared identifier FIRAuth`.
Please help.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You should import FirebaseAuth.

`@import FirebaseAuth;`

Answer (score 2):

Check if,

1) pod 'Firebase/Auth' is present or not

2) In app delegate have you configured using the below method

```
@import Firebase;
// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
[FIRApp configure];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it would be helpful!But it's in swift

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]? = [:]) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    FIRApp.configure()

    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    return true
  }
```

After that you can use it like this!

```
     @IBAction func signUpDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject)
  {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Register",message: "Register",preferredStyle: .alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",style: .default) { action in

      let emailField = alert.textFields![0]
      let passwordField = alert.textFields![1]

      FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error == nil{
          FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.textFieldLoginEmail.text!, password: self.textFieldLoginPassword.text!, completion: nil)
        }
      })

    }
```